# Google Earth API Draw Polygon on mouse click

Tags: .net, google-earth-plugin

I am developing a wep app using google earth api. I want to allow user to draw polygon on mouse click e.g if click on point a then b and then c draw a polygon. And its possible to enable or disable this feature by click on "ON/OFF" button, e.g if I click on "ON" button then allow user to draw polygon and if click on "OFF" then don't allow user to draw. Please assist here.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the `Polyplot` example by James Stafford. You should be able to adapt it easily to your needs. http://www.barnabu.co.uk/geapi/polyplot/

**EDIT:**

You can also use the [GEarthExtensions library](http://code.google.com/p/earth-api-utility-library/) if you are wanting to test if a given point (latitude, longitude) is within the bounds of a given `polygon`.

```
var contains = polygon.containsPoint(
                 new geo.Point(point.getLatitude(), point.getLongitude()));
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply but how can I implement same as with Google Earth API and can plot place mark with in selected area that I have saved in db (latitude  and longitude).

Comment: That *is* in the Earth Api.

Comment: Thanks for reply, yea I got it, I have store latitude and longitude now is it possible to plot points only inside the polygon e.g I will pass all saved longitude and latitude and the exist in created polygon then plot marker. I am able to plot all point by using google earth api so now I want to filler these within the polygon. Please assist here for same.

Comment: You would need to post the code you are having trouble with for me to help properly...but if you just want a filled polygon then simply use the latitudes and longitudes to draw one. http://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/?exp=earth#creating_polygons

Comment: Hi thanks for reply, I have found a sample which will fill a near about requirement please have look, http://www.barnabu.co.uk/geapi/polyplot/  now I want to provide some value of latitudes and longitudes so that can be plotted with in earth if they exist in drawn polygon. Please give me any idea how can I do this, I have search out but not found any proper solution that how can search/plot points with in a polygon.

Comment: That is just the link I posted - what does *your code* look like? What *have you* tried? ...if you are looking to calculate if one point falls inside the bounds of a polygon then see my edit.

Comment: HI, thanks for reply the example http://www.barnabu.co.uk/geapi/polyplot/  you provide is very helpful, I want to implement same functionality just with one additional function, i.e I will add a new button add markup from db and (after creating polygon) click on that button get all saved longitude and latitude and plot only those that exist inside created polygon. So can I use http://www.barnabu.co.uk/geapi/polyplot/ code in my application and add additional feature.

Comment: Polyplot draws a linestring instead of a proper polygon. It may not be quite what the OP needs.

Comment: @JuannStrauss - true, but as the OP provided no code I thought that polyplot would be a good starting point for him as it shows how to draw on the globe and how to capture user input coordinates. Once you have that creating linestrings is really no different from creating polygons or overlays, or any other geometry in the API.

Comment: I merely mention it because I have the same problem and the code samples on the Earth API forums are infuriatingly useless in the real world. To use polyplot, one has to apply quite advanced trigonometry to create and additional 3 (or more actually) points and then use the GE extension library's pointInPoly() function to determine whether points are within the bounds. It's madness.